# В Идее требует указать тип данных в списке

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите разобраться,что нужно сделать, что бы Идея не подсвечивало эту ошибку,ведь она сама по умолчанию должна указывать такой же тип данных как и в инициализации списка.Даже не компилирует и выдает ошибку.

Возможно нужно что-то указать в настройках проекта?

На всякий случай- Jdk 10.0.2.

---

@ ermak0ff   [image]

### 10 лвл.Пробовал менять лвл,но идея все равно ругается на всех лвлах.

@Эникейщик Возможно я не прав или где-то не правильно выразился,но раньше было обязательно указывать тип данных при инициализации списка,в более новых версиях сделали так, что при объявление списка,его тип данных по дефолту идет в инициализацию. 
 То есть c List list= new List(); 
 Упростили до Listlist =new List<>(); и по дефолту в <> будет Integer.

Comment: Для начала нужно скопировать код и вставить его в вопрос текстом, а не изображением.

Comment: "ведь она сама по умолчанию должна указывать такой же тип данных " - почему такое мнение?

Comment: Если нажать `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S`, что увидим в `Project language level`?

Comment: У вас не та версия java определена для компиляции или выполнения

Answer (score 1):

@ermak0ff поменял лвл языка в модулях и все заработало.Спасибо за подсказку.